# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urx'

Tags: python, spyder

my code fails, when I try to import the urx library.

```py
import urx

robot = urx.Robot("192.168.0.100")
```

I already installed the library (`pip install urx`).
If I run the installer again it says:

`Requirement already satisfied: urx in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.11.0) Requirement already satisfied: math3d in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from urx) (3.4.1)`

Does any of you have an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are running your code in the same environment where you installed the library.

Comment: okey, but how do i find out which enviroment im unsing and in which enviroment the library lies?

Comment: Where are you running your code from?

Comment: I'm using Spyder. It is installed here:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python

Comment: Have you created virtual environment?

Comment: Please put the code and error message into code blocks. You can [edit] your question. You said in the comments that you use the Spyder IDE, if that is the case, please add the [tag:spyder] tag to your question.

Comment: I moved the folders now manually to the path C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs. Now it works. 

Thanks for the Information @asynts. I will try to create the next question like this right away.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, mine got resolved by checking ***inherit global site-packages*** in PyCharm

**`File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Add Local Interpreter -> Inherit global site-packages`**